# how I can create a excel file in asp.net out of a listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, listview, printing

i have two question to asp.net and listview. I have a webapplication with a listview. this listview fill with data from users by active directory. the listview show only searched user.

Question 1:

I want to import this ListView in a Excel file. How I can do this? Must I use CSV for this?

Question 2:

I want print out this listview. How I can do this or is it better if I make a excel file and the user print this file :/

I need tipps ans good links :)

thanks <3

Answer (score 1):

1 - Please check these links about how to export listview to excel file :

http://forums.asp.net/p/1245474/2583840.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vasanthks/export-gridviewlistview-to-excel-with-color-formatting/

http://www.dotnetlogix.com/article/aspnet/56/How-to-export-listview-in-excel-in-asp.net.html

2 - For Printing you can do Reporting :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to print out the list, then you can print from the web-interface. Create a page with the content you want to print and the follow these instructions:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp

Answer (score 0):

Question 1:  No, you don't need to use CSV. You could use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) for exporting to Excel. It does an amazing job and there's not much you can't do with it in terms of exporting.

Question 2:  I'd use the above, but it depends on the requirements of the person who's printing the file.  You could just dump a plain list, but Excel would be better IMHO.

Just to complete this... some pseudo code for you to generate a simple spreadsheet...

```
using OfficeOpenXml;

using (ExcelPackage outPackage = new ExcelPackage(YOUR_DESTINATION_FILENAME))
{
    // Add new worksheet
    ExcelWorksheet destWorkSheet = outPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Spreadsheet name");

    // Draw header
    destWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Header 1";
    destWorkSheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Header 2";

    // Loop through your data and add rows
    for (int i = 0; i < YOURDATA.Count; i++)
    {
        destWorkSheet.Cells[i+2, 1].Value = YOUR_DATA_1;
        destWorkSheet.Cells[i+2, 2].Value = YOUR_DATA_2;
    }

    // Save spreadsheet
    outPackage.Save();
}
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        string fileName="filname.xlsm";Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",  string.Format("attachment;filename={0}",fileName));
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        ListView1.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

well for printing and saving to Excel , PDF, Word and printing purposes i prefer using RDLC as  its easier to maintain it. i don't have good experience using this third party office controls and dlls.